# how to create templated-like namespace for member functions

Tags: c++, function, class, templates, namespaces

I am curretntly trying to define a namespace/struct which contain function pointers which store a specific implementations (let's say a structure to contain several functions). For now everything works fine with the following structure:

```
class foo{
    int a;
    int b;

public:
    explicit foo(int _a, int _b) : a(_a), b(_b) {};
    std::function<int(int)> bar(int num) = [=](int num) -> int{
         // here I need to know a and b
         //do something with num and return 
    }
}
```

This class contains several functions where each has to know a and b. The problem is that I have to create and instance of the class and set the parameters a and b, which I would rather omit.
In another class I use this class only by taking its functions. Namely

```
class foo2{
    //some other parameters
    int a, b;
    std::function<...> fun1, fun2,...;
public:
    foo2(int a, int b, ....){this->a = a; this->b = b;};
    setFuncs(){
        foo instance(a, b); 
        this->fun1 = [instance](int num){ return instance.bar(num);}
        this->fun2 = ...
    }
}
```

but i want to omit creating a new class inctance each time (in the sense that I repeat the above behavior in the same class but another place in the code). I tried to template this class as

```
template<int a, int b>
class foo{
...
}
```

so i could assign the funtions as:

```
this->fun1 = foo<a,b>::bar;
```

But then I would need to know a and b at compile time, which is not possible. Those parameters are set once in class foo2. I realise the overall code may not be clean, I'm a physicist, not IT guy, as you can see. One way would be to store an instance of class foo in class foo2 and initialize it once for the whole class and let the functions fun1, fun2,... have access by reference to those pointers, but I 'm looking if there is another way (maybe a template like class, where I don't need to know the values at compile time).
Also I can't paste the whole code here as it contains thousands of lines in several files and describing what the code does is very hard. I appreciate any help and apologize if this may be a stupid or trivial question (i don't work in IT strictly, I'm a physicist ;) )

Comment: I think you might have an XY problem. I feel you want some sort of premade parametrization of functions, but I don't get your intensions clearly. You want objects that offer certain functionality but have predefined inputs for a larger scope than single function call. You might miss a certain design pattern or perhaps simply overcomplicate the (XY) problem.

Comment: "The problem is that I have to create and instance of the class and set the parameters a and b, which I would rather omit" - this is inevitable if you want any state to hold longer than a single function call. You want something to stay/be applied for longer, so (unless it's compile-time data) a state is inevitable. All solutions will just differ how that data is encapsulated - member of struct, capturing lambda, `std::function` with state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want some input data to stay longer than a single function call, unless it's fully compile-time data a runtime state is inevitable. The question is *how* you want this data to be encapsulated - different approaches will yield very different (subjective) feelings of how convenient they are.

Based on your usage example:

```cpp
this->fun1 = foo<a,b>::bar;
```

If you want to avoid state (or rather encapsulate it) you can create a factory that will create functions for you:

```cpp
std::function<int(int)> make_func(int a, int b)
{
    return [=](int x){ return actual_function(a, b, x); };
}

this->fun1 = make_func(a, b); // now std::function will hold lambda's captured state
```

This topic is generally known as partial application and I guess boost or other libraries already have a lot of supporting code for such manipulations.

Comment: this is actually a very interesting ide, thanks! I might use it! I'm currently thinking how to generelise this idea, because I have about 10 functions in the foo class. On one hand I could create such a construct and choose the appropriate function by an enum in a switch-case declaration and replace the class overall, on the other hand I could keep the class and create a factory for each function seperately. Both ways should work, is there a reason to choose one over another?

Comment: I don't get your question. 10 functions in the foo class - but why? Do they share anything (e.g. `a`, `b` variables). Why do you need an enum to choose implementation? Wh y not call specific implementation immediately?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes they all share a, b and I want to omit passing them as variables to the function. In general the piece of code I refer to is:

Comment: https://pastebin.com/kq4tksKd  The code is long, in general my problem refers to creating an instance of class __builtins as seen in one of the constructor of class operators. A few different classes create an object of type operators with using the enum and then choosing the appropriate function, that is why i wanted to omit creating a runtime state. EDIT: here a,b are denoted as 'L' and 'config'

Comment: Some state is unavoidable, and `std::function` has some internal state too (if you know how it's implemented). I roughly know what you want, but 1) I still have doubts about how you want it to be abstracted 2) it would be much easier for me if you post an MCVE to improve OR an unfinished MCVE to modify (with some gaps in code to fill). The paste you posted does not compile and could be significantly reduced.

Comment: "Some state is unavoidable, and std::function has some internal state too " - yeah I know. Tha is another issue which i need to get into to maybe replace it with a lambda, because a call to a lambda is much faster than std::function, but it doesn't matter now. Here I have a compiling piece of code with usage: https://pastebin.com/f38QQqyJ. It is not a minimal example, but if necessary I can just throw out some declarations in the class I don't use now. I did not do that because you mentioned that this code can be significantly reduced and I'd love to hear some suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: This is too much. I had to add 2 includes (`<vector>` and `<climits>`) and it still spills many warnings. Please reduce it to minimal API (you can fake/mock some stuff) and a simple main function that demonstrates usage. https://pastebin.com/8RdD7sgm

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! I didn't have time to create a minimal API, but in the end I'm gonna use your answer with the function generators. In the future I'll try to state more clear questions!

Answer (score 0):

You could create the lambdas in the `foo` constructor where the values of `a` and `b` are known.

Then you could also capture `this` to use the member variables (in case they change between the lambda creation and the call).

```
class foo
{
    int a;
    int b;

public:
    // No need for explicit since this isn't a "conversion" constructor
    foo(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b)
    {
        bar = [this](int x)
        {
            // Use the argument together with this->a and this->b...
            return some_value;
        };
    }

    std::function<int(int)> bar;
};
```

Comment: what would be the difference in declaring the function bar in the constructor against setting it as const outside the constructor call? is there any reason why this could be better? by creating an instance the other class members (as bar) are set with the set parameters a,b which will not change for this specific instance

Comment: @Qant123 Outside of any member function (the constructor included) it's not possible to access `this`. And it's not possible to access any (non-static) member variable if you don't have an object.

Comment: I see. Now I'm confused how my approached worked. By having = in the lambda capture the functions declared outside the constructor still new non-static data memebrs. But nevertheless this approach was prone to errors, thanks!